# When does the callback attached to <firebase-ref>.onDisconnect.remove() fire?

Tags: angularjs, callback, firebase

I am using AngularJS and Firebase to build a web app. Firebase docs say that an optional callback can be attached to [onDisconnect().remove()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/ondisconnect/remove.html). I expected that this callback fires only when the remove event completes. However, it fires as soon as the callback is attached. I attach the callback as follows:

```
var ref = new Firebase("some-ref-url");
ref.onDisconnect().remove(function(err) {
    console.log("remove callback firing");
});
ref.set(true);
```

Is there a way to ensure that the callback fires only when the user disconnects and NOT as soon as it gets attached?

Minimal working example based on how I intend to use onDisconnect().remove():

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.7/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.2/angularfire.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">{{hw}}</div>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', ['firebase']);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($firebase, $scope) {
        var ref1 = new Firebase("https://<my-app>.firebaseio.com/test1");
        var ref2 = new Firebase("https://<my-app>.firebaseio.com/test2");
        ref1.onDisconnect().remove(function(){
          console.log('remove callback firing');
          ref2.set(true);
        });

        $scope.hw = "Hello, World!";
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above code, ref2 is set to true on page load (instead of when the user disconnects). How to ensure that ref2 is set to true only when the user disconnects? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great question! Keep in mind that onDisconnect() is a server-side feature. The client-side equivalent is .info/connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A handler that you attach to `onDisconnect()` runs *on the Firebase servers* when they detect that the user has disconnected. There is no way for the completion handler to fire on your client anymore at that stage.

In this case it is better to split the logic in two:

- [what needs to happen on the server when the user gets disconnected](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-presence)?
- [what needs to happen on the client when the user gets disconnected](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-connection-state)?

The first one is handled with a `onDisconnect()` handler, the latter you'd handle with a `.info/connected` value listener. I've linked to the programming guide for each above.

Comment: Ah, the optional callbacks are used to confirm whether the onDisconnect was correctly attached or not. I misunderstood their use. Thanks.